# Send Data from DynamoDB to Lambda (C#) and to Azure Queue

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services

I am a beginner and trying to send data from AWS DynamoDB to Azure Queues. Note that this code will be invoked **10,000 and alot more**. Can you guys review it once.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

using Newtonsoft.Json;

using Amazon.Lambda.Core;
using Amazon.Lambda.DynamoDBEvents;
using Amazon.DynamoDBv2.Model;
using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

    // Assembly attribute to enable the Lambda function's JSON input to be converted into a .NET class.
    [assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer))]

namespace Lambda
{
    public class Function
    {
        private static readonly JsonSerializer _jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();

        public async Task FunctionHandler(DynamoDBEvent dynamoEvent, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            context.Logger.LogLine($"Beginning to process {dynamoEvent.Records.Count} records...");

            foreach (var record in dynamoEvent.Records)
            {
                context.Logger.LogLine($"Event ID: {record.EventID}");
                context.Logger.LogLine($"Event Name: {record.EventName}");

                string streamRecordJson = SerializeStreamRecord(record.Dynamodb);
                await Send(streamRecordJson);
                context.Logger.LogLine($"DynamoDB Record:");
                context.Logger.LogLine(streamRecordJson );
            }

            context.Logger.LogLine("Stream processing complete.");
        }

        private static async Task Send(string stream)
        {
            const string connectionString = "QUEUE END POINT";
            string queueName = "QUEUE NAME";
            ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder svc = new ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
            ServiceBusConnection svc1 = new ServiceBusConnection(svc);
            var client = new QueueClient(svc1, queueName, ReceiveMode.PeekLock, RetryPolicy.Default);
            var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stream));
            await client.SendAsync(message);
        }

        private string SerializeStreamRecord(StreamRecord streamRecord)
        {
            using (var writer = new StringWriter())
            {
                _jsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, streamRecord);
                return writer.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the connection and queue name are not changing per record then there is no reason to be creating a new client for each record in the loop. Especially for the amount of times stated in the original post.

Move that to the constructor of the class.

```
public class Function {
    private static readonly JsonSerializer _jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
    private readonly IQueueClient client;
    private const string connectionString = "QUEUE END POINT";
    private const string queueName = "QUEUE NAME";

    public Function() {            
        ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder builder = new ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
        ServiceBusConnection connection = new ServiceBusConnection(builder);
        client = new QueueClient(connection, queueName, ReceiveMode.PeekLock, RetryPolicy.Default);
    }

    public async Task FunctionHandler(DynamoDBEvent dynamoEvent, ILambdaContext context) {
        var logger = context.Logger;
        logger.LogLine($"Beginning to process {dynamoEvent.Records.Count} records...");

        foreach (var record in dynamoEvent.Records) {
            logger.LogLine($"Event ID: {record.EventID}");
            logger.LogLine($"Event Name: {record.EventName}");

            string streamRecordJson = SerializeStreamRecord(record.Dynamodb);
            await SendAsync(streamRecordJson);

            logger.LogLine($"DynamoDB Record:");
            logger.LogLine(streamRecordJson);
        }

        context.Logger.LogLine("Stream processing complete.");
    }

    private Task SendAsync(string body) {
        var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body));
        return client.SendAsync(message);
    }

    private string SerializeStreamRecord(StreamRecord streamRecord) {
        using (var writer = new StringWriter()) {
            _jsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, streamRecord);
            return writer.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you think I should make the azure client static? Or doing that will create issues?

Comment: @Unbreakable I that case you would need to make the function constructor static as well to avoid overrides but I do not see that as being an issue.